# randomly pick number from a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

How can i randomly pick a number from the given following matrix below?

```
    A=[0.06 0.47 0.47]
```

I just want to randomly pick a number from the matrix above. I am doing this in matlab enviornment. please help.
 Also, Is it possible assume a variable in matlab that tends to zero, like we do in limits?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your matrix is `M` then to pick a random element with uniform probability you can use [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html):

```
 M(randi(numel(M)))
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes, using [randi](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html):

```
A(randi(numel(A)))
```

Comment: `length` can be not suitable if the array's dimensions are bigger than 1.

Comment: True, but the example is 1 x 3 so this does what is asked. I guess that answering the question in general is probably better than just working with the example, though.